# alternate of percentile function of hive in Redshift

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-redshift

I have a script in hive, which is using `percentile` function as percentile(bigint,0.5), ie. percentile(10,0.5).

I need to convert this script to Redshift but there is no function by this name here.

Is there any existing alternate function available on Redshift, for hive's percentile function?

I am new to Hive and don't know exactly what must be best here.
Thanks for Reading.

Comment: https://popsql.com/learn-sql/redshift/how-to-calculate-percentiles-in-redshift

Comment: @leftjoin i think this is percentile continue function. Its probably not same as percentile. now its upto OP.